# Retain Variable's Value after refreshing a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, static-variables

I want to refresh a web page and retain the value of the variable (created in javascript) when the page is reloaded.

for eg:
 var cnt = 5;
 cnt++;

I want the value of 'cnt' to be 6 even after I refresh a page. How can I do it?

Comment: cookies- http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how you can do this, except by using cookies or session.

Answer (score 3):

Store the values in cookies or use browser local storage.

Read this for more info http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_webstorage.asp

Answer (score 0):

Or put them after the hash tag.

var cnt=5; -> refresh page with adding hash to the url:

http://domain.com/index.php#cnt=5

then extract it after reload...

Google: window.location.hash